# My css bootstrapclass ".hidden.xs" not working

Tags: html, css

***This is supposed to show no icons in mobile device.***

```
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .hidden-xs {
    display: none !important;
  }
}
```

*so this "Menu" gotta be hidden, but its showing all these icons still.*

```
<li>
    <a href="menu-categories.html">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cutlery"></span><br class="hidden-xs"> Menu
    </a>
</li>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've added the `hidden-xs` to the `<br>` element instead of the `span.glyphicon`. Change your code to this instead

```
<li>
    <a href="menu-categories.html">
       <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cutlery hidden-xs"></span><br> Menu
    </a>
</li>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have assigned `<br>` the target class which will not do anything. Instead add the class to the `<span>`

Answer (score 0):

```css
@media  screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  .hidden-xs, .glyphicon{
    display: none !important;
  }
}
```

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<li>
    <a href="menu-categories.html">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cutlery"></span><br class="hidden-xs"> Menu
    </a>
</li>
```

- `@media  screen and (max-width: 767px)` add on screen
- add css `display:none;` on both class`.hidden-xs, .glyphicon`